# Is there a function in excel office JS to insert table columns next to the selected table column?

Tags: office-js

i am trying to mimic the following functionality provided by excel itself via office JS, where i can select a table column in excel and insert a new column to the left:

[image: Add Table Columns to the left]

I know that i can insert Columns via the `Excel.TableColumnCollection.add(index, values, name)` Method using the index parameter:

```
index
number
Optional. Specifies the relative position of the new column. 
If null or -1, the addition happens at the end. 
Columns with a higher index will be shifted to the side. Zero-indexed.
```

But how can i find the index of the selected column in the table? i am aware of how to get the selected range, but not the selected column index of a table.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the column object by getItem() and them you could get the index from the column object.

Here is the sample code, it will insert the column on the left of the column title that you are selected

```
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sample");
    const expensesTable = sheet.tables.getItem("ExpensesTable");
    var range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
    range.load("values");
    await context.sync();
    var colname = range.values[0][0];
    var col = expensesTable.columns.getItem(colname);
    col.load("index");
    await context.sync();
    
    expensesTable.columns.add(col.index, [
      ["Deductable?"],
      ["Yes"],
      ["Yes"],
      ["No"],
      ["No"],
      ["Yes"],
      ["Yes"],
      ["No"],
      ["Yes"],
      ["Yes"],
      ["No"]
    ]);

    sheet.getUsedRange().format.autofitColumns();
    sheet.getUsedRange().format.autofitRows();

    await context.sync();
  });
```